# When dealing with big excel in R, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, how to save big excel with ffbase?

Tags: java, r, excel, ffbase

I was stuck at the last step, saving my excel.

The error is :

```
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) :
```

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

**therefore I searched and tried:**

```
> options(java.parameters=’-Xmx4g’)
Error: unexpected input在"options(java.parameters=’"里
```

And it doesn’t works,should I download any other package to run it?

**Also, I checked ffbase, however**

I don’t quite understand how to use it in real,
I simply need to save my file as excel, didn’t see much real case on the internet.

````
> ffsave(dirtydata2, file="~/dirtydata2.xlsx")
Error in dirname(filelist[[1]]) :数```

Also,I’m so sorry for my such basic questions.
Any learning website suggest for such level?
The help document does not have much real case.

Thank you for your time and patience.
````

Comment: The second error you’re seeing is because you’re not using straight quotes (`'`) for the string. The syntax highlighting should give you a hint that it isn’t being treated as a string! But fundamentally you might avoid your issue by using a different package (e.g. [‘readxl’](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/)) rather than the one you’re currently using.